# Battery life decreased drastically after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, power-management, battery

I had been using only Ubuntu in my laptop for nearly two years, and the battery life with Ubuntu 16.04 was pretty long. It would last for nearly 10-12 hours. But after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, it only lasts for about 3-4 hours (normal light use) and the percentage of the battery decreases with every passing minute. Is there any fix for it?

Comment: Do you have two graphics cards? I had the same problem, in 16.04 working good with Nvidia Optimus but it seems to have stopped working. I just disabled it in the BIOS and my battery and heat problems were resolved.

Comment: I have also witnessed a drastic drop after upgrading from 16.04 to 20.04 (I never switched to 18.04 though). I think 16.04 really was quite awesome in power management.

Answer (score 4):

First read this Ubuntu Help article about [Power & battery](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power.html)

If not enought you may want to install [TLP](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

*TLP brings you the benefits of advanced power management for Linux
without the need to understand every technical detail. TLP comes with
a default configuration already optimized for battery life, so you may
just install and forget it. Nevertheless TLP is highly customizable to
fulfil your specific requirements.*

Install TLP :

```
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

Then customize suspend setting : System Settings -> Power -> Suspend & Power Button.

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, and I finally found a solution, (but it may not be your case).
When you log in there is an option button, where you can choose from Gnome classics, Ubuntu and Ubuntu on wayland. I have been using Ubuntu on Wayland (because of some functions), and with this option the battery lasted max. 3 hours. So I changed it to Ubuntu, and now it works perfectly. I also updated the Kernel.

Hope it will work for you.